# Dart syntax kills me -> VoidCallback

Tags: flutter, dart

I use some code and can not understand this syntax philosophy:
Example:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

class SomeClass{
  VoidCallback _callback;

  set onCallback(VoidCallback callback){
      _callback = callback;
  }

  someFunction(){
    if(_callback != null){
      _callback();
    }
  }
}
```

...somewhere... in StatefulWidget class:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    someClass.onCallback = _onCallback;
  }

  _onCallback(){
    print('callback');
  }
```

I guess here `if(_callback != null){_callback()}` we initialize callback (if not correct me). But why in initState we call onCallback without parameters cause setter callback has voidcallback parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Dart, but I know Java, JavaScript, Groovy and C/C++ each to some extends.

Your are misinterpreting thing:

```
  set onCallback(VoidCallback callback){
    _callback = callback;
  }
```

`_callback = callback` is an assignment: we assign `_callback` with the value of parameter `callback`.

Given by the signature of `onCallback`, and especially the **set**, the expression `someClass.onCallback = _onCallback` is also an assignment, except it invoke a *setter*.

To my understanding, `_callback` is a function but it default values is `null`. You can not invoke something that is `null`, because otherwise you would have an error: Java/Groovy would throw a `NullPointerException` and Dart probably something alike.

So the code below is checking that `_callback` is not null, before calling it:

```
  if(_callback != null){
      _callback();
  }
```

As said, I don't know Dart but seeing it act as *an alternative to JavaScript* (quoted from Wikipedia), you have the same concept: each object is reference and a reference may be `null`.

Comment: I start to understand a little. If it's not hard for you could you write it in Java.